# Recommended partition setup for two 128 GB SSDs

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have two 128 GB SSDs and want to install Ubuntu with them. At first I filled the first disk with a / partition. Then I made the second disk have a big /home partition. Is there a better way to get more space out of my setup on the first disk?

Answer (score 0):

Most setups don't need that much space on /. You could use a filesystem that can use more than one partition or you could use LVM to make a 180gb /home and a ~64gb /. Honestly though, I think thats overkill for a simple private system. I always use symlinks in these situations:

- When your /home reaches 75% find a bigger directory that won't change size that much
- Create /home2/username on / and chown to your user
- Move the bigger dir to /home2/username
- And link it with 'ln -s /home2/username/Music ~/Music'

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution would have been to format both partitions in BTRFS, may be link them all in multi-disk setup and use virtual partitions over it. It would have allowed you to utilize all free space without worries where folder is kept or create extra robustness by duplicating data + a load of cool features.